# Given matrix $A^2$, how to find matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Let $$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ Knowing that $A$ has positive eigenvalues, what is $A$?

---

What I did was the following:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$$

so

$$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 + bc & ab+bd \\
ac+cd & bc+d^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I got stuck here after trying to solve the 4 equations. Can someone help, please?

Comment: This isn’t unique, as both $I, -I$and $ \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{matrix} \right]$ when squared are the identity.(there are infinitely many examples of matrices who’s square is $I$)

Comment: If $A^2$ was diagonal, would it help? If yes, how can you turn it into a diagonal matrix?

Comment: If $A=SJS^{-1}$ then $A^2=SJ^2S^{-1}$ where $S=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $J^2=\operatorname{diag}(1,4)$ (see [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B3%2C1%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%7D%7D)).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin post your comment as an answer, please.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the comment to @AlexeyBurdin until after I finished posting my answer

Comment: @user376343 can you (or someone willing to) [edit the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3743890/edit) to include the missing steps? Thanks. | J. W. Tanner that's fine)

Comment: Yet another solution: $$\pm\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\2&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing matrix powers can be done with diagonalization.

The eigenvalues of $A^2$ have sum $5$ (trace) and product $4$ (determinant), so they are $1$ and $4$.

The corresponding eigenvectors of $A^2$ are $\pmatrix{1\\-2}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\1}$, respectively.

Therefore, $A^2$ is diagonalized as follows:  $\pmatrix{1&1\\-2&1}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&4}\pmatrix{1&1\\-2&1}^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&1\\-2&1}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&4}\dfrac{\pmatrix{1&-1\\2&1}}3.$

Therefore, we can take $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\-2&1}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}\dfrac{\pmatrix{1&-1\\2&1}}3=\dfrac{\pmatrix{5&1\\2&4}}3$.

Answer (score 3):

For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, a square root of $B$ would have eigenvalues $\pm \sqrt{\lambda_1}$ and $\pm \sqrt{\lambda_2}$.  In your case you know you want the $+$ cases.  Find $u$ and $v$ so that
$\sqrt{\lambda_1} = u + \lambda_1 v$ and $\sqrt{\lambda_2} = u + \lambda_2 v$, and then take
$A = u I + v B$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have $A=SJS^{-1}$ where $J$ is in [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), then $A^2=SJ^2S^{-1}$.
By performing Jordan decomposition on $A^2$ given, we have $$
S=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\2&1
\end{pmatrix}
,\;J=\operatorname{diag}(1,4).$$
Then, obviously, $$S\cdot(\operatorname{diag}(1,2))\cdot S^{-1}=\dfrac13
\begin{pmatrix}5&1\\2&4
\end{pmatrix}$$ will be the only choice for $A$ if we prove that $A^2$ has the same $S$ for Jordan decomposition, as $A$ has.

---

EDIT

To prove the above, it suffices to realize that $A$ and $A^2$ share eigenvectors. Indeed, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda,$ then $$A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=\lambda^2v$$